# How to get custom logs in jmeter via command line

Tags: logging, command-line, jmeter

[image]
It has 10 http requests and each request sends an id in its response data. I need to capture these ids while running my test through **command** **line** so that i can see in logs.

Can someone please guide me on **detailed** **steps** for the same?

i have a jtl file , can it be used for logs and check id field from the same? is there any way out for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the same by using different ways to get the same.

1. First way to get the same is to extract the `id` using [JSON extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor/) and declaring it using [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables), this way the id's will be added in the .jtl results file as the separate column

   JSON Extractor configuration:

   [image]

   the line to be added to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   sample_variables=id
   ```
2. Second way to get the same is using [__log() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__log), it allows printing arbitrary information to [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

   [image]
3. Third way to get the same is using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) so the IDs will be written into [STDOUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)). The relevant Groovy code:

   ```
   println(new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).id)
   ```

Comment: Thanks alot @Dmitri T!! It works for me....Have a great day!